# A component is changing a controlled input of type text to be uncontrolled - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, controlled-component

I have a page where i fetch data from server and setting value in state for controlled inputs. (e.g I have input which has value of `this.state.name`, i fetch name from server for example Dave and set it in state as name, so value of input is Dave. it works but i got problem with array of objects

so this is the state

```
this.state = {
        ingredients: [{ ingredient: "", quantity: '' }],
        //other properties
   }
```

and this is how i use `ingredients`

```
{this.state.ingredients.map(({ ingredient, quantity }, index) => (


   <div key={index}>
        ingredient: <input value={ingredient} className="ingredientClass" type="text" autoComplete="off" placeholder="e.g: pepper" onChange={{e => this.update(index, "ingredient", e.target.value)} />
        quantity: <input value={quantity} autoComplete="off" type="text" placeholder="e.g: 1g" onChange={e => this.update(index, "quantity", e.target.value)} />
        <button onClick={this.BtnClick}>delete</button> <br />
       {this.state.errorFor === 'ingredientsfield' ? this.state.errmsg : null}
   </div>
))}
```

But this causes this error:

> Warning: A component is changing a controlled input of type text to be uncontrolled. Input elements should not switch from controlled to uncontrolled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. More info: `link`

Why is that happening? How can I fix it?

P.S: i checked and ingredients are succesfully fetched from server

UPDATE: code of onChange event

```
update(index, key, value) {
    this.setState(({ ingredients }) => ({ ingredients: ingredients.map((ing, i) => i === index ? { ...ing, [key]: value } : ing) }));
    console.log(this.state.ingredients)
}
```

Comment: What is the initial value of ingredients before you fetch it?

Comment: strings... why does it matter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that one of inputs has undefined or null value at some moment.

I can't understand what changes your input value to null (undefined) from the code you show. But you can use ReactDevTools to observe the value of the input during your application running.

Comment: Logging my entire form's state on the change showed that was accidentally changing a different input to `undefined` causing the warning - thanks!